# React Native Jest: How to get a component state after triggering fireEvent.changeText()

Tags: reactjs, react-native, unit-testing, testing, jestjs

I have started learning Jest for testing react native code. During the process of learning i came across fireEvent.changeText() as this method will change the value. In my scenario I am making use of this method to perform textInput onChangeText. During TextInput onChangeText, I am updating the textinput value and along with that i am performing basic arithmetic operation and storing the result on another state variable.

I can access the textinput value by using the props.value but how can i access the component state variable value after the fireEvent.changeText().

Heres the code:

**Home.js**

```
import {Text, View, StyleSheet, TextInput} from 'react-native';
import React, {Component} from 'react';

export default class Home extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      arithmeticValue: 0,
      multiplyByTwoValue: 0,
    };
  }

  calculateArithmeticValueWithState = num => {
    this.setState({
      arithmeticValue: num,
      multiplyByTwoValue: num * 2,
    });
  };
  
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <View>
          <Text>Welcome to React Native... Second Snapshot Testing..</Text>
        </View>
        <View>
          <TextInput
            value={this.state.arithmeticValue}
            onChangeText={val => this.calculateArithmeticValueWithState(val)}
            placeholder={'Enter Postive Integer'}
            testID={'integer.textinput'}
            style={{
              borderColor: 'grey',
              borderWidth: 0.8,
              borderRadius: 2,
              width: 300,
            }}
          />
          <Text testID='mulByTwo.test'>{this.state.multiplyByTwoValue}</Text>
        </View>
      </View>
    )
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
});
```

**Home.test.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import Home from './home';
import renderer from 'react-test-renderer';
import {fireEvent, render} from '@testing-library/react-native';

it('Should apply the value when changing text', () => {
  const {getByTestId} = render(<Home />);
  fireEvent.changeText(getByTestId('integer.textinput'), 4);
  
  console.log(getByTestId('integer.textinput').props.value) // It return 4

  // Here how can i access the component state multiplyByTwo value and it should return 8 based on the logic of getByTestId('integer.textinput')
})
```

Searching a lot but could not find answer to it.

Answer (score 0):

Any update as I'm also struggling with this issue